# Integrating $\int{3\sin^2x\cos x \;dx}$

Tags: integration

I am struggling with the following integral:

$$\int{3\sin^2x\cos x \;dx}$$

I have so far tried to solve this using every tool at my disposal, I have set $t = \sin x$ but I get an even harder quantity to integrate:

$$\int{\frac{t^2-t^4}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt}$$

so I have dismissed this way of proceeding. Then I tried to rewrite $\sin^2x = 1-\cos^2x $ but as a result I get stuck at:

$$\int{3dx}-3\int \cos^3xdx$$

which I don't know how to cope with because integrating by parts I end up with an endless chain of integrals. Hope you could shed some light on the way to properly solve this, really feel a bit lost.

**Update: sorry I have made a mistake in copying the exercise over the site.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sin^2(x) \cos^2(x) = \dfrac{\sin^2(2x)}4 = \dfrac{1-\cos(4x)}8$$

**EDIT**

(Question was changed) Setting $\sin(x) = t$. We get that $\cos(x) dx = dt$. 
Hence, we have $$I = \int 3 \sin^2(x) \cos(x) dx = \int 3 t^2 dt$$

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, my question will probably sound stupid, but I'd like to ask why is that $dt = \cos(x)dx$ and don't we set $\cos(x) = \sin^{-1} t$ and then calculate the $dt$ value by derivating $\sin^{-1}$?

Comment: @Mary I assume you mean $x = \sin^{-1}(t)$ and then working out $dx$ from that. That is an inefficient way to go about. If you have $t = \sin(x)$, then $\dfrac{dt}{dx} = \cos(x) \implies dt = \cos(x) dx$

Answer (score 1):

Hint::
$\displaystyle \sin^2x = \frac{1 - \cos 2x}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \cos^2x = \frac{1 + \cos 2x}{2}$

Edit:: Let $\sin x = t $ then $\cos x dx = dt$, then you have $\int 3t^2  dt $

Answer (score 1):

If you let $t=\sin x$,  you get $dt = \cos x dx$, so $$\int{3\sin^2x\cos x \;dx}=\int 3t^2dt=t^3+C=\sin^3x+C$$

Answer (score 1):

In the integrand, if all arguments of trig functions are "the *x*", transform all of them into sin's and cos's. Every *m* and *n* below matches any integer.

- cos<sup>2*m*</sup>(*x*) sin<sup>2*n*</sup>(*x*) where *m* and *n* are nonnegative: discussed below.
- cos<sup>2*n*+1</sup>(*x*) *f*(cos<sup>2</sup>*x*, sin *x*): set *y* = sin *x*.
- sin<sup>2*n*+1</sup>(*x*) *f*(sin<sup>2</sup>*x*, cos *x*): set *y* = cos *x*.

If the integrand matches none of these, transform it into tan's and sec's.

- sec<sup>2*n*</sup>(*x*) *f*(tan *x*, sec<sup>2</sup> *x*): set *y* = tan *x*.

If none of the above work, apply the *sneaky* Weierstrass substitution.
$$ y = \tan \frac x 2 = \frac {\sin x} {\cos x + 1}. $$

### Integrate cos<sup>2*m*</sup>(*x*) sin<sup>2*n*</sup>(*x*)

Find the less of *m* and *n*. Assume *n* < *m*, **extract** sin(2*x*)<sup>2*n*</sup> with
$$ \cos x \sin x = \frac {\sin 2x} 2.$$

There will be either only cos's or only sin's left. Convert them into double-angles with
\begin{align}
\cos^2 x &= \frac {1 + \cos 2x} 2 \\
\sin^2 x &= \frac {1 - \cos 2x} 2.
\end{align}